# Magento2: How to disable admin category page cache in magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to disable admin category cache page in magento2

Thanks

Comment: what you mean by  `admin category cache page`?

Comment: yes in admin category page cache

Comment: Why do you think category page is cached at admin?

Comment: sometime cache issue happen and my client ask to remove the only for admin category

Comment: I do not think Magento cache creates an issue for your client. I guess that there  might be some additional cache at the server level is creating issue.

Comment: Thanks for your update